# Parsing XML weather forecast data using PHP and simpleXML

Tags: php, xml

I am trying parse the following XML weather forecast data using the PHP simpleXML extension:

http://www.pakenhamweather.info/test/IDV10753.xml

I have tried a number of times to parse this XML but to no avail. The following is an example:

```
$product = simplexml_load_file("http://www.pakenhamweather.info/test/IDV10753.xml");

foreach ($product->forecast->area[2]->forecast-period[0] as $blah) {
    printf(
    "<p>Forecast Icon: $s</p><p>Precipitation Range: $s</p>"
    $blah->element["forecast_icon_code"]
    $blah->element["precipitation_range"]
    );
}
```

For the purposes of this example, I have simplified the example by selecting 'area[2]' and 'forecast-period[0]', but ideally, I would like to specify the 'area' by the 'description' attribute and 'forecast-period' based on the 'index' attribute.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: _“but ideally, I would like to specify the 'area' by the 'description' attribute and 'forecast-period' based on the 'index' attribute”_ – then you should probably go look into XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to get area by attribute and forecast-period by attribute.

```
$product = simplexml_load_file("http://www.pakenhamweather.info/test/IDV10753.xml");
$forecasts = $product->forecast->xpath("//area[@description='Mildura']/forecast-period[@index='1']");
foreach ($forecasts as $forecast) {
    $forecast_icon_code = $forecast->xpath("element[@type='forecast_icon_code']")[0];
    $precipitation_range = $forecast->xpath("element[@type='precipitation_range']")[0];
    echo $forecast_icon_code . "===" . $precipitation_range;
}
```

Just replace the attribute values which you want to pick

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much @dileep-kumar for helping me out. I never made the connection between simplexml and xpath despite reading about both of them.